# SNORT list interfaces on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-programming, snort

Using SNORT in Windows you can execute:

```
C:\Snort\bin> snort -W
```

This will provide a numbered list of interfaces similar to the image below:

[image: SNORT - list of interfaces]

On Linux, there is no -W option. How do you print a numbered list of interfaces in Linux? (I am not looking for answers about $ ifconfig -a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `ip link show`.

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:17:02:40:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

From [Linux: Show / Display Available Network Interfaces](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-network-interfaces-names-command/)

Comment: Thanks, SNORT accepts this numbering as input for it's interface option.